# Xml C# Html Encode Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, soap

I am using a method - getComments - to retrieve user input and using xmlElements to my soap webservice. At the point the method is called I am receiving a null reference and VStudio asks me to great a new object. Here is the code where I am receiving the error:

```
XmlElement msgbodyElement = (XmlElement)messageElement.ChildNodes[0];
        msgbodyElement.InnerText = HttpUtility.UrlEncode (getCommentInformation());
```

Ideas? Specific error: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Thank you.

Comment: `Here is the code where I am receiving the error`, yeah so which of the two is throwing the exception? And what is the exact exception?

Comment: Use your debugger....

Comment: Wow...sorry.. The exception is in msgbodyElement at getComments()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why this was voted down twice, nor why people feel they have to sound rude online....Debugging is the first step yes?

Thank you to Jim for reminding me to check the nodes but turns out it was not that. Stepping through the code I found that it was the order of the code.

Answer (score 1):

From this code, the messageElement is null or it doesnt have a child node or getCommentInformation raises an exception inside.

Comment: Ah...thank you. I didn't even think to check the child node. I will try it. Thank you for being nice about it, I'm a bit new at this.